# Process large stack through the deep with dask

Tags: python, dask

I try to process a large stack (I get the array from landsat and make stack, space-time like a 3d matrix), this is a small example:

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

da_list = [da.from_array(np.full((int(1e3), int(1e3)), fill), (1000,1000)) for fill in [1,2,3,np.nan]]
stack = da.dstack(da_list)

print(da.nanmean(stack, axis=2).compute())
```

This process good, but it load whole stack in the memory for process, if the stack is more large like this:

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

da_list = [da.from_array(np.full((int(1e5), int(1e5)), fill), (1000,1000)) for fill in [1,2,3,np.nan]]
stack = da.dstack(da_list)

print(da.nanmean(stack, axis=2).compute())
```

But this need a lot of memory for process, what is the best method for process in parallel and not required a lot of memory for process?. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, if you actually want `np.full`, you should just use `da.full`.  However I assume that you are just using `np.full` as an example for some other function that produces a numpy array.

The answer is that you can't call your function immediately, you need to delay calling it until you actually need the result.  To do this, use [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html)

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
from dask import delayed

delayed_list = [delayed(np.full)((1000, 1000), fill) 
                for fill in [1, 2, 3, np.nan]]

da_list = [da.from_delayed(d, shape=(1000, 1000), dtype=float) 
           for d in delayed_list]

stack = da.stack(da_list, axis=2)

>>> stack
dask.array<stack-0..., shape=(1000, 1000, 4), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1000, 1000, 1)>
```

So far you haven't actually done any work.  You have never called `np.full` (or whatever your function is).  Dask will only start calling these functions once you tell it to, for example when you call `.compute()`.  However it will call these functions in an order so that *hopefully* it can process some of the large arrays down to small ones (such as by using `nanmean`) before calling more.

This blogpost may be more informative: http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/01/17/dask-images